# Missing "null analysis" section in Eclipse compiler settings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I do not see the "**Null Analysis**" section in the 
Compiler "Error / Warnings" settings in **Eclipse Kepler**

I use :

```
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

I use SDK 1.7.

Is there any preliminary setting required to get this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows->Compiler->Error/Warnings/NullAnalysis
Try out Mars 4.5 M2. Lot of bugs have been fixed with respect to Null analysis and overall.
Please also check: https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis.

Comment: The problem is this section does not even show up :
The last section I have in Errors/Warning is "Annotations"

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot. Can you if possible try out a Mars build. I will download a Kepler build and check.

Comment: I checked with Version: 4.3.2
Build id: M20140221-1700.

It is a Kepler build. I see the option.